# CodedUiTest doesn't run on Windows Server 2012 Terminal Server

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2012

I try to run a CodedUiTest project under Windows Server 2012 Terminal Server, VS 2012.
And gets an exception in the output window: The system cannot find the file specified.
When I try to debug the test project another exception occurs: Process with an Id of -1 is not running.

And if I do the same actions under Windows 7, VS 2012 everything goes well.

Comment: Terminal Server is a complicated beast of its own (security, permissions, desktop handling etc.)... any reason you want to do this on Terminal Server?

Comment: Programmers work on terminal server. So I do really need to do this on Terminal Server

Comment: Then check with MS Support how to configure VS 2012 in a Terminal Server environment...

Comment: Is there any way to check, which file the system can't find?

Comment: you could try to log all file access with sysinternals (free download from MS) - perhaps you find a hint... BUT: this won't solve your problem - TALK to MS Support about VS 2012 and Terminal Server, they can tell what/how/whether this works!